# What's the difference between layout-large-v11 and layout-xlarge

Tags: android, layout

I'm working on a Tablet application.

What's the difference between this two res folders: layout-large-v11 and layout-xlarge?
The first option is from the IOSched app.

Are both valid for tablets? Which one is better for design tablets layouts?

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

v11 is there to help distinguish between large devices that are still running older versions of android. This distinguishing is necessary because there were some big changes at Android 3.0 (version 11 of the api), in terms of style. So the v11 allows you to say "Ok, if this is a newer version of android, use this newer style of layout, other wise use this older style".

Bottom line, you only need to use it if you want to provide two different layouts: one for versions of android that are pre-3.0, and one for versions that are post-3.0. v11 actually has nothing to do with the size of the screen itself, merely what version of android you're running on.

Comment: Hi Kurtis, thanks for the fast answer :)
Im developing exclusively for tablets 3.0+
In that case I don't have to use layout-large-v11, right? I could use only res/layout, if my app doesn't suppor other version.

Comment: Correct. No need to mess around with v11 for you.